# Combine swagger Definition files

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am generating a swagger definition for all the my APIs by annotating the source code.

I was wondering if there is any way for make possible merge all the APIs in one single `json` file?

*Note:* I am using `Swagger 2.0` definitions.

Comment: Was this issue resolved "Geek"? It will help others/community if you can provide a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy those apps in a WebSphere Liberty server with the apiDiscovery-1.0 feature defined in your server.xml, then you can simply go into (GET) /ibm/api/docs and retrieve your aggregated JSON file.  You can also retrieve it as YAML, by adding the Accept header "application/yaml".

You can download it for free at wasdev.net then just run the installUtility command to grab the feature (wlp/bin installUtility install apiDiscovery-1.0).

More information in this blog: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2016/04/13/deploying-swagger-enabled-endpoints-websphere-liberty-bluemix-api-connect/

Comment: Looks interesting. Can it merge into one mater swagger json file if you put two swagger files in a folder?

Comment: Each swagger document has to be in a different web module (i.e. in a different WAR file), then they will be combined into a master json file.  This is the behaviour from WebSphere Liberty's API support via the apiDiscovery-1.0 feature.